# How to specify delete subdirectories named "abc" or "def" using find in linux

Tags: regex, linux, find

If I want to remove all subdirectories (and sub-subdirectories etc.) named "Win32" from current directory, I would do

```
find . -type d -name Win32 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

However, what if I want to remove subdirectories named "Win32" or "x64"? I've tried using regular expressions after "-name", e.g.

```
find . -type d -name "\(Win32\|x64\)" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
find . -type d \( -name Win32 -o -name x64 \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o` logic combinator: `find . -type d -name Win32 -o -name x64`

To use regular expressions you can use the -regex option.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to remind you to be careful if you prefer the regex way:

```
find . -type d -regex '^.*\/\(Win32\|x64\)$'
```

while I'd prefer using the **-o** as other users have mentioned.  ;)